# C# Embed an image in an outlook email

Tags: c#, outlook, html-email, office-automation

I am trying to send emails with the same logo on it every time but I cannot seem to get any image to appear, the code I have done is as follows:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            String attachmentDisplayName = "MyAttachment";
            string imageSrc = "C:\\Users\\Test\\Pictures\\image.jfif";
            Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMailItem.Attachments.Add(imageSrc, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, null, attachmentDisplayName);

            string imageContentid = "someimage.jpg";
            oAttach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E", imageContentid);
            oMailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format(
                "<body>Hello,<br><br>This is an example of an embedded image:<br><br><img src=\"cid:{0}\"><br><br>Regards,<br>Tarik</body>",
                imageContentid);

            oMailItem.To = textBox1.Text;
            oMailItem.Subject = textBox3.Text;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get the same results when you add the `image.jfif` manually to the message body?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. But I've noticed the following image format used in the code:

```
image.jfif
```

I'd recommend checking any other file format like PNG, JPEG.

You may find the [PNG, GIF, or JPEG? Which is the Best Image Format for Email?](https://www.litmus.com/blog/png-gif-or-jpeg-which-ones-should-you-use-in-email/) article helpful.

---

The following code works like a charm on my side:

```
 Attachment attachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(
     @"E:\Pictures\image001.jpg"
    , OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem
    , null
    , "Some image display name"
    );

   string imageCid = "image001.jpg@123";

   attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty(
     "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
    , imageCid
    );

   newMail.HTMLBody = String.Format(
     "<body><img src=\"cid:{0}\"></body>"
    , imageCid
    );
```

You may also try to change the second parameter passed to the [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.add) method in the following way:

```
Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMailItem.Attachments.Add(imageSrc, Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, null, attachmentDisplayName);
```

Pass the `OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem` instead.